# Исключение scans [C]

Tags: c

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRAISE "How are you?"

int main(void)
{
    char name[40];
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке ввести строку в scans выдает исключение

```
Ошибка  C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details
```

Если изменить scans на scans_f то выдает уже другое исключение

```
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFDE1BD217D (ucrtbased.dll) в First.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0000008C91100000.
```

Код скопирован из учебника (Язык программирования C. Стивен Прата), но не смотря на это работать не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?

Пробовал убирать scans и вводить строку через переменную, все работает.

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: Если уж используете `scanf_s`, то используйте правильно, передавая по **два** параметра для одного `%s`.

Comment: Ты вообще в курсе, что такое исключение?

Answer (score 1):

Ну что мешает сообщение об ошибке прочитать?

> Ошибка  C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. **To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.** See online help for details

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

И что мешает верно использовать `scanf_s`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRAISE "How are you?"

int main()
{
    char name[40];
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf_s("%s", name, 40);
    printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мешает исключительно опыт, которого 2.5 дня:)

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в самом верху:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

Скорее всего, решение не верное, но работает.